# SQL Join on first matched field

Tags: sql

I have a query to join 2 tables in the following way.

Table1 has a field (LinkTo) that may (or may not) appear in one of three fields in table Table2 (Link, Link1, Link2).  I need try joining LinkTo to Link, then Link1 then Link2.  As soon as I match on one (say Link1) I should stop trying to join.

Thanks

Mark

Comment: Why do you care about the order that it tries the match? A t1 row will join with a t2 row if `t1.LinkTo IN (T2.Link, T2.Link1,T2.Link2)` why do you need to prescribe exactly how the query is executed?

Comment: @Martin: It's probably called "business requirements" :-)

Comment: Is there anyway to have a field indicating which join was done say 'LinkedwithLink2' if it linked with link2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be what you are looking for. It joins in the order of fields you mentioned (**edited** to answer a question from the comments):

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.*,
    CASE WHEN (t1.LINKTO = t2.LINK) THEN 'LinkedWithLink' 
         WHEN (t1.LINKTO <> t2.LINK 
           AND t1.LINKTO = t2.LINK1) THEN 'LinkedWithLink1' 
         WHEN (t1.LINKTO <> t2.LINK1 
           AND t1.LINKTO <> t2.LINK1 
           AND t1.LINKTO = t2.LINK2) THEN 'LinkedWithLink2' END AS chosen_join
FROM TABLE1 t1 
[LEFT OUTER] JOIN TABLE2 t2
ON (t1.LINKTO = t2.LINK OR 
   (t1.LINKTO <> t2.LINK AND t1.LINKTO = t2.LINK1) OR
   (t1.LINKTO <> t2.LINK1 AND t1.LINKTO <> t2.LINK1 AND t1.LINKTO = t2.LINK2)
```

Note, I don't know whether you need a `LEFT OUTER` join or not... In any case, you should be aware of a potentially very slow execution plan with this...

Comment: s there anyway to have a field indicating which join was done say 'LinkedwithLink2' if it linked with link2? –

Comment: Thanks Lukas I appreciate it alot.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE1 t1
  JOIN TABLE2 t2 ON (t1.LINKTO = t2.LINK OR 
                     t1.LINKTO = t2.LINK1 OR
                     t1.LINKTO = t2.LINK2)
```

As soon as one of statements is true other does not checks

Comment: I wouldn't be sure about that... Depends on the RDBMS

Comment: Thanks it is true. I just have experience with oracle